# How to create custom filenames in C?

Tags: c, string, file-io, fopen

Please see this piece of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fp = fopen("/*what should go here??*/","w");
        //I need to create files with names: file0.txt, file1.txt, file2.txt etc
        //i.e. file{i}.txt
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    char filename[sizeof "file100.txt"];

    sprintf(filename, "file%03d.txt", i);
    fp = fopen(filename,"w");
}
```

Comment: notice how he put `%03d`. strictly speaking, you just need `%d` to do what you asked, but this will pad it to 3 digits with leading 0s, so that they will sorted properly by your OS (well... windows is kind of clever about that actually, but still, leading 0s are cool!)

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf()` with `"file%d.txt" and`i` to generate the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `snprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char szFileName[255] = {0};
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sprintf(szFileName, "File%d.txt", i);
    fp = fopen(szFileName,"w");
}
```

Comment: uhm... me thinks you forgot to edit a line when you copy pasted ;)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, and its nice to be fast on down votes...maybe try reload answer faster next time

Comment: 255 is quite a large buffer. At least your solution will do well for extremely large values of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    char name[12];
    sprintf(name, "file%d.txt", i);
    fp = fopen(name, "w");
}
```